# Wine won't let apps go fullscreen

Tags: wine, fullscreen

[image]

When I try to play Diablo 1 on WINE it only plays the game in this window and there is no option to maximize or anything it is really obnoxious. I am using virtual desktop with a 1200x720 resolution, please help!!

Comment: Try without a virtual desktop, then.

Answer (score 3):

Disable the Virtual Desktop in winecfg